# Graphviz Format: "jpeg" not recognized

Tags: python, jpeg, graphviz, dot

Running the following code (example from https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/):

```
from graphviz import Digraph
dot = Digraph(comment='The Round Table', format='jpeg')
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')
dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')
dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)
```

Results in:

```
Format: "jpeg" not recognized. Use one of:
```

It seems like graphviz cannot write a file to any format. How to solve this?

Comment: Off-topic, but: it's a really bad idea to store images of graphs as JPEGs. Consider using a vector format, or, if you want to rasterize, a lossless format like PNG.

Comment: Looks like jpeg is not enabled in your version of dot. What does the command `dot -v` give, when issued in a command window? (also give a `<cntrl>C` to leave the dot program again).

Answer (score 1):

My method: (I'm win10, other op may skip to step 2)

1. Add "bin/" of Graphviz into environment path.

   - My Graphviz installation path: `D:\software\graphviz\Graphviz2.44.1\`. It has 4 folders: "bin","include","lib","share"
   - So I add `D:\software\graphviz\Graphviz2.44.1\bin` to my environment path
2. cmd run command "dot -c" to config.

   - `dot` means `D:\software\graphviz\Graphviz2.44.1\bin\dot.exe`. Due to step 1, I just need to run `dot -c`, otherwise, I need to run `D:\software\graphviz\Graphviz2.44.1\bin\dot.exe -c`
   - `dot -c` means: Configure plugins (Writes $prefix/lib/graphviz/config with available plugin information.  Needs write privilege.)
3. Add path to your code:

```
# add
import os 
path_graphviz = "D:/software/graphviz/Graphviz2.44.1/bin" # replace by your Graphviz bin path
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path_graphviz

# origin code
from graphviz import Digraph
dot = Digraph(comment='The Round Table', format='jpeg')
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')
dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')
dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)
```

4. I success on my computer.
   [here is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDsi6.png)

Comment: Running `dot -c` as Administrator fixed the Format not recognized error. I also had to copy dot.exe to neato.exe to be able to use neato. Thanks!